# Javascript: str.indexOf not working with £ symbol

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't working.

The user inputs a string that I'm converting to pennies (1 pound = 100 pennies). If the string contains the £ symbol as the first character, I know to multiply it by 100 for the conversion.

My problem is that I'm using an if statement to see if the first character is £. I'm using `indexOf()`, but it doesn't catch the character £. I've even used `console.log(userInput.indexOf("£"));` to see what is returned, and it logs `0`. As far as I can tell, this only doesn't work in the if statement.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="main">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title></title>
    <script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController">
        <input type="submit" ng-click="trim()">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Angular**

```
$scope.trim = function(){
    var userInput = "£1234";

    if(userInput.indexOf("£") == 0){
        userInput = userInput.substr(1);
        userInput *= 100;

    }

}
```

I have been using `£123`for `userInput`, and when I enter it, it displays `you have entered an invalid character`. All help is appreciated.

Comment: `console.log(userInput.indexOf("£"))` will help

Comment: You're checking to see if `£` is the *first* character. What if there's whitespace in front of it?

Comment: You'll need to turn the code blocks above into a [mcve] (which is easily done using the `<>` toolbar button and adding necessary libs, etc.). Bottom line: If there's a £ in the string, `indexOf` **will** find it.

Comment: and change your line `userInput *= 100;` to `userInput = +userInput * 100;`

Comment: @AndrewEvt: No need, `*` coerces just like unary `+` does. The code above *is* a bit chaotic, though, returning a number in one case (there was a `£`) and a string in another (there wasn't).

Comment: @AndrewEvt I appreciate the advice, but your missing my question: the `if(userInput.indexOf("£") == 0){` never fires, despite £ being the first character

Comment: yes, but code looks better, isn't it?)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fxdq3ez2/ @user5854440 chech this pls. I think `userInput` doesn't contain `£`, just add `console.log(userInput)` before if

Comment: @AndrewEvt I'm not sure where else the issue could be; as I stated, I used `console.log(userInput.indexOf("£"));` to make sure it was returning `0`, and it was. For some reason, this if statement isn't running.

Comment: `console.log(userInput.indexOf("£")); if(userInput.indexOf("£") == 0){
        userInput = userInput.substr(1);
        userInput *= 100;
    }` make so - and show us output pls

Comment: @user5854440: If `userInput.indexOf("£")` is `0`, `if (userInput.indexOf("£") == 0)` ***will*** branch into the block attached to the `if`. If you think that isn't happening, it's observational error. Either `userInput.indexOf("£")` is not `0`, or the block is being executed, just not doing what you expect. Again: Do up a [mcve] and we can help. Without one, we can't.

Comment: @AndrewEvt: No. Let's not stumble about in the dark with a `console.log` torch. Let's switch on the lights with a debugger.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I removed pieces of my code that are not a part of the issue.

Comment: `userInput` now is equal toooo.... what?

Comment: "abc£".indexOf("£") outputs 3 as index, so the problem is not the "£"

Comment: @AndrewEvt The user inputs what they wanted. as previously stated, I've been using `£123`, but I defaulted `userInput` to `£1234` above.

Comment: @user5854440: That's great, but the problem wasn't too much code. Again: Turn it into a Stack Snippet via the `<>` button. That's a **runnable** example. (Stack Snippets are basically the on-site analogue to jsFiddle or jsBin or CodePen, but a lot less feature-rich. Entirely up to this, though.) If you do that, then run it and make it fail; we'll be able to run it and make it fail, too, and explain to you what's going on.

Comment: Please make this a Stack Snippet... The answer to your problem will follow soon after.

Comment: if you checking against a known position, then i would change the test to `if (userInput[0] === '£') {`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gc9n3wc5/ - check fires on blur - all works fine, isn't it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I can't repeat this issue in stackoverflows snippit (it works there). I'm using sublime, and I'm not even connecting to localhost. I'm just opening it in browser. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @user5854440: I doubt it, but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

It is not your `userInput.indexOf("£") == 0` that didn't work.  It is due to your line

```
userInput = userInput.substr(1);
```

It should be that your editor saved the file as UTF-8, and the HTML page character encoding says it is ISO-8859-1.  Now `"£".length` is `2` and your `userInput.substr(1)` doesn't work.  It will need to be `userInput.substr(2)` in this case, but I think it is better to match the file encoding with the `<meta charset="...">`.

You can change your file's encoding to ISO-8859-1, and it would work expected.  (In Emacs, using `C-x Return f`, and choose `iso-8859-1` and save the file again).

Or simply state `<meta charset="utf-8">` to match with your file's encoding, and `userInput.substr(1)` would work as expected.

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/g91wvsp6/1/

This sample page is using `<meta charset="utf-8">` and is working with the expected result.

Comment: It *could* be a charset issue, but just blindly adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` isn't the solution. Handling charsets correctly throughout (both the script and the HTML, any backends being used, etc.) would be a solution.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is not "blindly adding `<meta charset="utf-8">`"

Comment: Yes, **now** the answer actually says something more. It didn't when I posted the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

*(This community wiki answer inspired by [太極者無極而生's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36898028/157247), but seemed like to big an edit to make to that answer.)*

It sounds like an encoding mismatch issue. If your JavaScript file is encoded with one charset (say, ISO-8859-1, which some Windows tools call "ANSI") but your server is serving it with another charset (say, UTF-8), the `£` character in your file will not be correctly recognized. If the file is ISO-8859-1 served as UTF-8, `£` will be an invalid character. If the file is UTF-8 served as ISO-8859-1, it will be *two* characters. In either case, it won't match the `£` input by the user.

To correct it:

1. Ensure you know what encoding your JavaScript (and HTML, CSS, etc.) file is actually saved in. Your text editor should have features around doing that. If your page is primarily in a western text such as English, I strongly recommend UTF-8.
2. Ensure you use the same encoding for your HTML and JavaScript files. I'm sure it's possible to use different encoding for them, but it's going to be a pain. Keep life simple and use the same encoding throughout.
3. Ensure that your server is correctly identifying the charset when serving those resources, for instance when sending the `Content-Type` response header, it should be `Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8` for a UTF-8 JavaScript file (not just `Content-Type: application/javascript`).